# search keywords in a list and create new list

Tags: python

i'm trying to search keywords in a list, if the list has no keywords it should return a specific string.

i tried below program to do but , unable to achieve.

```
data = ['CUSTOMER/client1', 'DC/Dc1', 'OS/windows', 'PRODUCT/p1', '']

newdata = []
for d in data:
    if 'CUSTOMER' in d:
        newdata.append(d)
    else:
        newdata.append('No Customer')
    if 'DC' in d:
        newdata.append(d)
    else:
        newdata.append('No DC')
    if 'OS' in d:
        newdata.append(d)
    else:
        newdata.append('No OS')
    if 'PRODUCT' in d:
        newdata.append(d)
    else:
        newdata.append('No Product')
    if 'TYPE' in d:
        newdata.append(d)
    else:
        newdata.append('NO Type')

print(newdata)
```

My output:

```
['CUSTOMER/client1', 'No DC', 'No OS', 'No Product', 'NO Type', 'No Customer', 'DC/Dc1', 'No OS', 'No Product', 'NO Type', 'No Customer', 'No DC', 'OS/windows', 'No Product', 'NO Type', 'No Customer', 'No DC', 'No OS', 'PRODUCT/p1', 'NO Type', 'No Customer', 'No DC', 'No OS', 'No Product', 'NO Type']
```

i'm looking to get for input

case1:

```
data = ['CUSTOMER/client1', 'DC/Dc1', 'OS/windows', 'PRODUCT/p1', '']

newdata = ['CUSTOMER/client1', 'DC/Dc1', 'OS/windows', 'PRODUCT/p1', 'NOTYPE']
```

case2:

```
data2 = ['CUSTOMER/client1', 'OS/windows', 'Type/type1','','']

newdata2 = ['CUSTOMER/client1', 'NODC','OS/windows','NOPRODUCT', 'Type/type1']
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are iterating over your data array and that for every element you are testing the element and then setting newdata[] based on whether THAT element matches. Since each element exists only a single time in data, I suspect newdata[] is populated with repetitive instances of your 'not-found' entry. You should read up on the python any() statement. It's what you are looking for.

Comment: @user590028 the problem using `any` here is that it will tell you if the keyword exists, but you still need to get the value, and `any` can't do that. It just returns `True`/`False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that you are searching for the records one by one and for each record you appending negative result for all the other values, not only the one being searched.

What you should do here is to see if the keyword is there and get its value, or append negative value for only that particular value.

Here is a possible solution

```py
data = ['CUSTOMER/client1', 'DC/Dc1', 'OS/windows', 'PRODUCT/p1', '']
newdata = []

customer = [s for s in data if "CUSTOMER" in s]
newdata.append(customer[0] if customer else "No Product")

dc = [s for s in data if "DC" in s]
newdata.append(dc[0] if dc else "No DC")

os = [s for s in data if "OS" in s]
newdata.append(os[0] if os else "No Product")

product = [s for s in data if "PRODUCT" in s]
newdata.append(product[0] if product else "No Product")

type = [s for s in data if "TYPE" in s]
newdata.append(type[0] if type else "No Type")
```

Here is the output

```
['CUSTOMER/client1', 'DC/Dc1', 'OS/windows', 'PRODUCT/p1', 'No Type']
```

This solution though has the complexity of **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**, as for each of the *n* values in the list you iterate over the whole list (in total *n* iterations).

---

To reduce the complexity of the algorithm you may convert the list into a *dictionary*. Those have **O(1)** lookup.

To convert the `list` to `dict` you may do the following.

```py
data = dict(d.split('/') for d in data if "/" in d)
```

You will have the following

`{'CUSTOMER': 'client1', 'DC': 'Dc1', 'OS': 'windows', 'PRODUCT': 'p1'}`

Now you can iterate through the keywords and get whatever you want:

```py
data = dict(d.split('/') for d in data if "/" in d)

keywords = ['CUSTOMER', 'DC', 'OS', 'PRODUCT', 'TYPE']
newdata = []

for k in keywords:
    newdata.append(f"{k}/{data[k]}" if k in data else f"No {k}")
```

You'll get:

`['CUSTOMER/client1', 'DC/Dc1', 'OS/windows', 'PRODUCT/p1', 'No TYPE']`

In this case you iterate once over the initial `data` list once (performing *n* iterations) and you iterate over the `keywords` once (overall *n* iterations), thus the final complexity is **O(n)**.

---

In this particular example the number of elements in the list is not that much, so you shouldn't worry too much about complexity, but in similar cases with more values the latter answer would save some time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to find keywords and return the values stored in the keywords, then you should use dictionaries but not lists. This is because dictionaries are made via key-value pairs. Sorry if this is not what you were looking for as I could not ask for clarification since I can't comment yet :C .
Ex code:

```
t={"re": 12,"HI":1}
x = t.get("re")
print(x)
```

This will yield 12.

Comment: for some data we don't have keys to search.check case1 &2 for some data model

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem is that for each item in `data` you will print **at least one message per each keyword**. Whether it is the value or the "Not Found" message.

To overcome this you should loop on your keywords and check if they are present **anywhere** in your `data`:

```py
data = ['CUSTOMER/client1', 'DC/Dc1', 'OS/windows', 'PRODUCT/p1', '']
keywords = ['CUSTOMER', 'DC', 'OS', 'PRODUCT', 'TYPE']

newdata = []
for k in keywords:
    for d in data:
        if k in d:
            newdata.append(d)
            break
    else:
        newdata.append('No ' + k)

print(newdata)
```

Gives:

```
['CUSTOMER/client1', 'DC/Dc1', 'OS/windows', 'PRODUCT/p1', 'No TYPE']
```

---

But this loops on the whole `data` for each keyword and is very not efficient (`O(N^2)`). Another option is if you can alter your data structure, you should use a `dict`:

```py
data = {'CUSTOMER': 'client1', 
        'DC': 'Dc1', 
        'OS': 'windows', 
        'PRODUCT': 'p1'}
```

And now you can loop once on the keywords and retrieve the data in `O(1)` (total `O(N)`):

```py
newdata = {}
for k in keywords:
    newdata[k] = data.get(k, "No " + k)
```

And this will give as result:

```
{'CUSTOMER': 'client1', 
 'DC': 'Dc1', 
 'OS': 'windows', 
 'PRODUCT': 'p1', 
 'TYPE': 'No TYPE'}
```

Comment: for sometimes the data will result all blank. for that case also i need to write the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should be less time taking as just a single regex search for a keyword.

```
data = ['CUSTOMER/client1', 'DC/Dc1', 'OS/windows', 'PRODUCT/p1', '']
# data = ['CUSTOMER/client1', 'OS/windows', 'Type/type1','','']

newdata = []
data_joined = '|'.join(data) # Give delimiter such that it won't be in the input
keywords_opp_dict = {'CUSTOMER': 'No Customer', 'DC': 'No DC',
                     'OS': 'No OS', 'PRODUCT': 'No Product', 'TYPE': 'No Type'}

for key, opp in keywords_opp_dict.items():
    search_res = re.search(r'({0}[^|]*)|$'.format(key), data_joined, re.IGNORECASE).groups()[0]
    if search_res:
        newdata.append(search_res)
    else:
        newdata.append(opp)
```